# Universal App, enable support of earlier Windows Phone versions

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing application for Windows Phone Market. I have chosen Universal App template, as I would like to build Windows Store App at some point.

I noticed, target platform for Phone project is `Windows Phone 8.1`.

Is there any way to enable support of previous Windows Phone versions, like 8 or 7, for Universal App Template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible unfortunately.

The only way is to create WP 7 / 8 Silverlight Apps.